# Sublime, search whole file that contain specific words and replace whole line of code

Tags: sublimetext

```
<img src="/assets/default/img/activity/36.svg"
<script src="/assets/default/js/lines.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/default/vendors/chartjs/chart.min.css"/>
and so on...
```

Notice that each of these has the same words which contains `/assets/default/`.  How do I replace the whole line from the start of double quote to end of quote to `{{ asset('the whole words inside double quote') }}`?

So expected to be like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('assets/default/img/activity/36.svg') }}"
<script src="{{ asset('assets/default/js/lines.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/default/vendors/chartjs/chart.min.css') }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking about a regular expression search replace.  Bring up the normal find/replace panel (Find -> Replace ...), and clicke the `E` button (or maybe `.*` depending on your ST version) to turn on regular expressions.

You want to find things that start with your file path, and you want to capture the variable part of the path and use it again.  You can do that with an expression like this (in the Find input):

```
"/assets/default(.+?)"
```

Sublime will hightlight matches in the source as you type, so you can confirm it is working as you write.

Now you want to replace that with the `asset()` version, including the variable part you captured in brackets above.  You can do that with the following (in the Replace input):

```
"{{ asset('/assets/default$1') }}"
```

Comment: holy moly! this is what im looking for! thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and replace text in a number of files at once, press Command+Shift+F or **Control+Shift+H** to open Sublime Text's Find in Files tool that can search and replace across as many files as you have open or select from its menu.
For detail please [click here](https://zapier.com/blog/find-replace-guide/)